# Splunk: HDFS Capacity N/A

Tags: hadoop, monitoring, hdfs, splunk

I installed splunk to monitor and analyze hadoop jobs. After I installed splunk core and splunk hadoop app in Jobtracker, forwarder and TA on other nodes, the HDFS capacity and slots capacity shows N/A in Utilization section. any idea of possible causes?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HDFS and Slots showed N/A because the metrics were not enabled and Splunk didn't get the necessary information about HDFS capacity.

Here's what I did.

1. configure hadoop to send metrics
   http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/HadoopOps/latest/HadoopOps/SplunkTAforHadoopOps#Hadoop_metrics
2. configure splunk forwarders to monitor the output.
   http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/HadoopOps/latest/HadoopOps/SampleHadoopinputs.conffiles

Comment: Would be nice to include the snippents from the docs.splunk.com links. If the links to splunk docs change, we'll still know how to solve the problem.